# Extract single plot from ggplot with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want to produce some plots using ggplot and `facet_grid` and save the plot as an object. My problem is that I also want to save each subgroup (i.e. each facet) as an object separately. My question is now if you can extract a single facet from `facet_grid` and save it as an object? Here is some simple code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ am)
```

Now I'd like to produce two objects - one for `am=0` and one for `am=1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't use subsetting, but you can extract individual facets from a facet grid.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

p1 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ am)


g1 = ggplotGrob(p1)


# Rows and columns can be dropped from the layout.

# To show the layout:
gtable_show_layout(g1)

# Which columns (and/or rows) to drop?
# In this case drop columns 5 and 6 to leave am = 0 plot
# Drop columns 4 and 5 to leave am = 1 plot

# am = 0 plot
g1_am0 = g1[,-c(5,6)]

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1_am0)


# am = 1 plot
g1_am1 = g1[,-c(4,5)]

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1_am1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subset your data on way in and remove the facet command.

```
ggplot(data = subset(mtcars,am==0), aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point() 

ggplot(data = subset(mtcars,am==1), aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()
```

I realized I didn't answer your question about saving as object.
Before the ggplot code add a line :

```
tiff(file="firstfolder from working dir/next folder/ name.tiff",units="in",width=5,height=6,res=72)
```

You will need to add `dev.off()`after the plot code to see stuff print to your computer screen again.

You can use png, pdf, etc...for different formats.

If it is just a one off, and you are using RStudio, you can export manually from the plot window.  See Export button above it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually know about subsetting but I was wondering if there is an elegant way just to extract the plots from facet_grid. This is interesting to me because the plots are very sophisticated (hence long code) and I want to keep the code as simple as possible..

Comment: Other than snapshotting or cropping, not that I know of @ehi

Comment: The problem with snapshotting is that there is not a seperate scale and y-axis label..