# How do I extract an individual graph from ggcoxdiagnostics dfBeta output in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Running ggcoxdiagnostics to produce dfBeta plots for a multivariate coxph regression model.

```
require(survival)
require(survminer)

# Dummy data
set.seed(100)
permth_int <- seq(10)
mortstat   <- c(rep(1,9),0)
age        <- runif(10,50,70)
sex        <- sample(seq(2),10,replace=T)
ill        <- sample(seq(3),10,replace=T)

# Create survival object
SO         <- Surv(permth_int,mortstat==1)

# Cox regression
model <- coxph(SO ~ age + sex + ill)   

# Produce diagnostics plot
plots <- ggcoxdiagnostics(model, type = "dfbeta",
                 linear.predictions = FALSE, ggtheme = theme_bw())
plots
```

It produces a grid of multiple graphs. I would like to reference these graphs one at a time. Is there an easy way to obtain an individual graph from the object produced by ggcoxdiagnostics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because `ggcoxdiagnostics` is calling `ggplot` and using a facet wrap for the predictor variables in the models. I've borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/users/419994/sandy-muspratt in an answer to [Extract single plot from ggplot with facet_grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218814/extract-single-plot-from-ggplot-with-facet-grid) and developed the following solution:

```
# You'll need these libraries
library(gtable)
library(grid)

# Get a ggplotGrob from your plots object
gr <- ggplotGrob(plots)

# Visually examine the layout grid that `plots` is drawn to
gtable_show_layout(gr)

# The first plot (`age` facet) occupies the first 6 columns of the grid 
gr1 <- gr[, 1:6]

# You'll need column 2 for the second and third plots, as it contains the y-axis label
gr2 <- gr[, c(2, 7:10)]

# Third plot:
gr3 <- gr[, c(2, 11:15)]

# Draw the third plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gr1)

# Draw the second plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gr2)

# Draw the second plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gr3)
```